Eclipse IDE dosn't luanch
I just installed Eclipse IDE 2024-09, but it won't launch when I click on it. The initial splash screen with the Eclipse logo briefly appears, then disappears, and the IDE doesn't open. Any suggestions?
I tried running it as an administrator, but it didn't work. I also deleted and reinstalled Eclipse, but the result was the same.

(1) Go to the Eclipse directory and check if there is any xxxx.log file. If so, see what message it contains. (2) OS is Windows ? Linux ? (3) How to install ? Use Installer ? or Use zip file ? (4) Have you installed JDK? Have you set JDK (set environment variables PATH, JAVA_HOME)?

I didn't find the .log file . My OS is windows & I installed Eclipse using the installer & Yes I download the JDK from oracle websites then I installed eclipse

Is your Windows version Windows 10 or Windows 11?

No my windows is 11

Which option did you pick in the Eclipse Installer? Where did you install it? Which Oracle JDK is it, and installed how?

Try installing eclipse with packages, select package based on your language :
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
